# Which set are these bags from? Red bricks, grey plates, and yellow railings?

Tags: set-identification

Can anyone help me identify which set these bags are from?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These are from: [60110-1: Fire Station](https://brickset.com/sets/60110-1/Fire-Station)

[image]